# su and sudo not installed, but I need root permission to install them

Tags: linux, docker, serverless-framework

I try to yum install package into docker container lambci/lambda:python3.6

I get the interactive console with

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task --entrypoint bash -it lambci/lambda:python3.6
```

but both su and sudo are not installed

then I try to install anything with

```
yum install
```

root permission is asked

How to solve this evil circle ?

Comment: su alone doesn't work?

Comment: @KoltPenny no gives "bash: su: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, you can try and run the image as root:

```
docker run -u root ...
```

That way, in your bash root session, you should be able to install what you want.
Keep in mind, that container will be stopped and eventually removed when your bash session ends.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the server directoy with the root user. It should be configured when the OS was installed.

If you are attempting to connect through a terminal, try "root@(server ip)".

If this doesn't help, please let us know how you log into the machine.

Comment: thx for the response. it is a docker container, I logged in with command described in the question